# Which expression could represent a database constraint to prevent time spans from overlapping?

Tags: database

I was doing some online assessment and this question was confusing to me. What is this question trying to say?

Which expression could represent a database constraint to prevent time spans from overlapping?

Select the correct answer:

```
A.  s1.start <= s2.end or s2.start <= s1.end 
B.  s1.start <= s2.start <= s2.end <= s1.end 
C.  s1.start <= s2.start and s1.end <= s2.end 
D.  s1.end <= s2.start or s2.end <= s1.start
```

Comment: there is an `and` / `or` missing in option b

Comment: Option b isn't missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will help if you plot s1/s2 (as series of `1` & `2`) comparing them

Consider S1 (shown as `111111111111111`) to be the benchmark positioned in time like a Gantt Chart which depicts its start and end.

```
              111111111111111
```

Now, relative to `111111111111111` position one or more `2`s that meets the first of the started condition. e.g. s1.start <= s2.end

```
              111111111111111
    22222222222  << these 2s are less than or equal to the beginning 1
```

Now position the next 2 according to the second condition, e.g. s2.start <= s1.end

```
              111111111111111
                            2  << this 2 is less than or equal to the last 1
```

so, taken together

```
              111111111111111
    2222222222222222222222222   s1.start <= s2.end or s2.start <= s1.end
```

Use the same approach on all pairs:

```
a             111111111111111
    2222222222222222222222222   s1.start <= s2.end or s2.start <= s1.end
    
b             111111111111111
               2222222222222   s1.start <= s2.start (and?) <= s2.end <= s1.end
    
c             111111111111111
               22222222222222222222 s1.start <= s2.start and s1.end <= s2.end
    
d             111111111111111
                            22222222  s1.end <= s2.start, or
       22222222                       s2.end <= s1.start
```

Comment: Still don't understand. Could you please elaborate more? Thanks!

Comment: You have not supplied the missing conjunction in option b. You should reply to reasonable questions that clarify the question. Although I probably should really wait for the needed clarification I have added something to my answer. If this fails to clarify then I don't believe I can help further.

Comment: Option b isn't missing anything. The question was asked as what I just typed up here. Everything is here.

Comment: OK seems very odd because this is true always `s2.start <= s2.end` : so it adds nothing novel or useful to the option. Regardless, do you now have an understanding of the options?